# Error while trying to write inputs to running console app with a batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, console, console-application

I have an exe file that I want to execute with a batch file.

Exe file is a third party console app that will prompt for input three times.

So I want to fill it in with an empty line, someText and someOtherText

```
(echo. echo someText echo someOtherText) | call config.exe remove
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read.
```

What could be the issue, please advise at least the direction to search?

I have the same error even if try to execute a simpler command like:

```
echo. | call config.exe remove
```

Comment: As mentioned in the previous question, there is no way you can fix it, unless you can either get hold of the developer of the code, or if you have the Source code.

Comment: You forgot `&` between the three `echo` commands. Then use `echo/` rather than `echo.`. And note that the trailing _spaces_ will also be echoed. Finally, there is no need to use `call` for an executable file…

Comment: @Gerhard, the previous question was about the syntax for the batch, here I hoped to find some workaround or hack to manage the error. Usually, there're no unsolvable tasks just tasks with weird workarounds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `config.exe` does not accept redirection at all. It requires real console buffers.

1. If you want to automate it, you could create another console application which will

- start your `config.exe` using [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)
- write your lines to [STD_INPUT_HANDLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) using [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) (ASCII, `\n` separated lines) or [WriteConsoleInputW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleinput) (if you need unicode characters)
- after write is complete, just wait for `config.exe` termination and return exit code

2. Another simpler option is [ConEmu terminal](https://conemu.github.io/) (I'm the author). There is [GuiMacro scripting](https://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html) which could be easily used from console. So you could just run from your prompt or wrap in in batch file (run in ConEmu):

   ConEmuC.exe -GuiMacro print "\nsomeText\nsome Other Text\n" & config.exe remove

Comment: My network security at work blocks your ConEmu terminal, but a solution with another console app works, it's running, thank you.

Comment: Which security product do you use, I wonder? If it's not a secret...